# esp-01 wifi module STM32F4 discovery firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, esp8266, stm32f4discovery, esp8266wifi

I want to send data to Firebase Realtime Database using stm32f4 and esp-01 wifi module.

this is how I tried to connect and send to firebase Realtime Database
[connect firebase and send message funciton](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jc3ww.png)

```
void fireBaseConnectSend(char *firebaseUrl,char 
*firebaseAuthKey,char *sampleData)
{

char postRequest[500];
char data[100];
sprintf(postRequest, "POST /data.json HTTP/1.1\r\n");
strcat(postRequest, "Host: ");
strcat(postRequest, firebaseUrl);
strcat(postRequest, "\r\n");
strcat(postRequest, "Content-Type: application/json\r\n");
sprintf(data, "Content-Length: %d\r\n", strlen(sampleData));
strcat(postRequest, data);
strcat(postRequest, "Authorization: key=");
strcat(postRequest, firebaseAuthKey);
strcat(postRequest, "\r\n\r\n");
strcat(postRequest, sampleData);

Uart_flush();
Uart_sendstring("AT+CIPSTART=\"TCP\",\"");
Uart_sendstring(firebaseUrl);
Uart_sendstring("\",443\r\n");
HAL_Delay(500);
char chipsend[100];
sprintf(chipsend,"AT+CIPSEND=%d\r\n",strlen(postRequest));
Uart_sendstring(chipsend);
HAL_Delay(500);
Uart_sendstring(postRequest);
}
```

here I tried to send this text

```
POST /data.json HTTP/1.1
Host: sera-37bfe-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: <message Lenght>
Authorization: key=fxzpXdBWhZZeyfRCDOwWfD4YVp3lAusIytFMzxqh

<Message>
```

[calls the function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQSZ4.png)

```
fireBaseConnectSend(HOSTAPP, authKey, " 
{\"sensor\":\"temperature\",\"value\":25}");
```

The message returned from ESP
[esp message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QCiA.png)
it connects to the fireabase but I think firebase doesn't recognize my message and I couldnt find the solution.

this is my esp initialize
[esp initialize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZxBg.png)

```
void ESP_Init (char *SSID, char *PASSWD, char *STAIP)
{
char data[80];

Ringbuf_init();

Uart_sendstring("AT+RST\r\n");
HAL_Delay(2000);

/********* AT **********/
Uart_flush();
Uart_sendstring("AT\r\n");
while(!(Wait_for("OK\r\n")));


/********* AT+CWMODE=1 **********/
Uart_flush();
Uart_sendstring("AT+CWMODE=1\r\n");
while (!(Wait_for("OK\r\n")));

/* Set Static IP Address */
/********* AT+CWSTAIP=IPADDRESS **********/
Uart_flush();
sprintf (data, "AT+CIPSTA=\"%s\"\r\n", STAIP);
Uart_sendstring(data);
while (!(Wait_for("OK\r\n")));

/********* AT+CWJAP="SSID","PASSWD" **********/
Uart_flush();
sprintf (data, "AT+CWJAP=\"%s\",\"%s\"\r\n", SSID, PASSWD);
Uart_sendstring(data);
while (!(Wait_for("OK\r\n")));

/********* AT+CIPMUX **********/
Uart_flush();
Uart_sendstring("AT+CIPMUX=0\r\n");
while (!(Wait_for("OK\r\n")));
}
```

I was expecting something like this
[expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MDqL.png)

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please [don't show pictures of text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code#dont-use-screenshots-of-text). Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search. You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

Comment: What is the `sampleData` looks like? You set the content type as `application/json` but according to the error message, you seems sending the plain text instead of a serialised json object.

Comment: {\"sensor\":\"temperature\",\"value\":25} this is the sampleData I tried to send